# Mongoose.js: What are QueryStreams

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I looked through the documentation of mongoosejs odm and found following:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/querystream.html

What are they used for? What can I do with them.

I am not sure if they are used for streaming docs or for dynamicly updating queries...

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's all about the API.

`QueryStream` allows to to use `ReadStream`'s API so in order to appreciate `QueryStream`, you need to know more about `ReadStream`/`WriteStream`.

There are many pros:

- You can process large amount of data, which you'll be getting as "chunks" so the memory contains one item at a time (it could of a DB document, DB row, a single line from the file, etc.)
- You can pause/resume the stream(s)
- You can pipe read->write very easily

The idea is that it gives you a **unified API** for read and write operations.

To answer your question "What can I do with them":

You could do anything with or without node.js's stream API but it definitely makes it clearer and easier to use when there's some sort of standard.

Also, node.js's streams are event-based (based on EventEmitter) so it helps with decoupling.

---

Edit:

That was more about the aspect of streams. In Mongoose's case, a single chunk contains a document.

To clarify the advantage of the API:

node.js's `http.ServerResponse` is a writable-stream, which means you should be able to stream `Mongoose`'s resultset to the browser using a single line:

```
// 'res' is the http response from your route's callback.
Posts.find().stream().pipe(res);
```

The point is that it doesn't matter if you're writing to `http.ServerResponse`, a file or anything else. As long as it implements a writable stream, it should work without changes.

---

Hope I made it clearer.

Comment: Hi, so if I understood you correct a QueryStream would be a good idea if I store videos in mongodb and want to stream them to the client. I can pause/resume and pick, also I don't have to wait until everything is loaded from the db but what about normal documents with string data. There I only have the unified API as benefit or are there other pros? Or can I forexample use a QueryStream for something like a messaging system too (no binary, buffs)?

Comment: @kyogron You don't have to use `QueryStream` to avoid loading the full resultset into the memory, using query.each() would also stream it but don't confuse it with the streams API. Having a standard API makes programming more obvious and pluggable. `QueryStream` is indeed a stream but each chunk represents a (whole) document. Also, MongoDB (currently) has a 16MB limit per document. If you're going to store videos in MongoDB, you'll need to split each file into multiple documents but what you're looking for already exists, look into `GridFS`. Can you clarify the messaging example?

Comment: @kyogron Also, I added an example of the API's advantage to the answer.